# Why does the leader wear a talis on the first night of s'lichos in a Chabad synagogue?

Tags: minhag, chazzan-prayer-leader, chabad, tallit-gadol, selichot

In *Chabad*-Lubavitch synagogues, it is customary that anyone who would not wear a *talis* normally [does not do so](/q/35568) just because he's leading/representing the congregation. The only exception of which I'm aware is the first day of *s'lichos* before *Rosh Hashana*: then ([in the middle of the night](/q/10243)), the *shaliach tzibur* wears a *talis* even though no one else does (and so he wouldn't, either, were he not leading the services). Why is that exception made?

---

<sub>(Note that I'm *not* asking the following: "Lubavitchers are careful for reasons of *kabala* not to wear a *talis* at night. Why is an exception made by the *shaliach tzibur* on the first night of *s'lichos*?" That's also an interesting question, but is not mine here.)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - To confirm that your question is accurate - see [Shaarei Halacha U'Minhag - page 226 - at the top](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15787&st=&pgnum=221) which mentions that for Selichos the Chabad Minhag is to wear a Tallis.

2 - The main reason for this is based on [Rosh Hashana 17b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9718&st=&pgnum=36&hilite=) where it says Hashem put on a Talis and said the Shelosh Esrei Midos. Therefore we emulate this by the Chazan putting on the Talis and saying the Shelosh Esrei Midos. אמר רבי יוחנן: אלמלא מקרא כתוב אי אפשר לאמרו:
" מלמד שנתעטף הקב"ה כשליח צבור והראה לו למשה סדר תפילה. אמר לו: כל זמן שישראל חוטאין יעשו לפני כסדר הזה ואני מוחל להם" 
ראש השנה י"ז:

see:
אהלי תורה' גיליון תתנ"א עמ' 50 ואילך, ובפרט בעמ' 62

Comment: Is ר״ה _Chabad_'s source? I mean, _Chabad_ says the 13 _midos_ daily.

Comment: That is what it says in Oholai Torah. Not available online.